# How to use public-key encryption in Py4A scripts?

Tags: android, encryption, public-key-encryption, sl4a

I'm developing an Py4a (Python in SL4a) application running on an Android phone.
The application collects some sensitive data, and then sends it via e-mail, using the smtplib module.
To assure necessary protection, I need to encrypt that information.
As phone is considered to be unsafe device, I have to use the public-key encryption, and only recipient's public key should be stored in the phone.

The standard Py4a distribution contains two packages supporting public key cryptography:
the `ssl` and `gdata`.
Unfortunately none of them provides a ready to use function, allowing me to encrypt longer information with the private key.
Well, I know that in fact I should generate a random temporary symmetric key, encrypt my information with that key, and finally encrypt only this key with the recipient's public key. However there are some details which must be considered to obtain secure solution...

So here my question comes. Is there any simple encryption library, well suited to Py4a (ie. based on the cryptographic libraries already available in Py4a - like ssl and gdata.Crypto) providing easy to use public key encryption?

**Update 2013.06.13**

I have performed some experiments with the gdata library in Py4a.
Finally I have get the following "quick&dirty" solution:

```
import gdata.tlslite.utils.keyfactory as rk
#Generate the recipient's RSA key
sec=rk.generateRSAKey(1024)
#obtain the publickey, which will be stored
#in the sender mobile phone
pubxml=sec.writeXMLPublicKey()
print pubxml
#Create the public key from XML
pub=rk.parseXMLKey(pubxml)
#
#Now lets simulate the sender
#It has only access to "pub" 
#
import gdata.tlslite.utils.PyCrypto_AES as sk
import gdata.tlslite.utils.cipherfactory as cf
#Generate random key and initioalization vectors
key=sk.getRandomBytes(32)
iv=sk.getRandomBytes(16)

#Here we should check if the key and iv are reasonable
#Now we accept them as they are

#Text to encrypt
txt1="Strictly secret unknown text!"
#Pad the text to the length N*16
padlen=16-(len(txt1) % 16)
if padlen:
   txt1=txt1.ljust(len(txt1)+padlen, " ")
#Create the AES key
ak=cf.createAES(key.tostring(),iv.tostring())
#Encrypt text
ctxt1=ak.encrypt(txt1)
#Encrypt key and initialization vector with recipients publickey
ckey1=pub.encrypt(key+iv)
#
# Now we simulate the recipient
# It has its secret key 'sec', and received encrypted key
# and iv from the sender in ckey1. It also receives ctxt1
#
pkey1=sec.decrypt(ckey1)
pkey=pkey1[0:32]
piv=pkey1[32:48]
# Now we decipher the text
pak=cf.createAES(pkey.tostring(),piv.tostring())
ptxt1=pak.decrypt(ctxt1)
# Print the deciphered text
print ptxt1
```

Probably this solution is far from being optimal, but it at least works.

Comment: A few comments: you should use a proper cryptographic padding, your libraries should support one (PKCS#1/7 padding, etc.). No need to encrypt the IV, you can send it along with the ciphertext. Ideally you should use HMAC with a different key (or authenticated encryption, but that's probably not supported) to ensure the ciphertext hasn't been tampered with (Google 'padding oracle').

Answer (score 0):

Because the phone is an unsecure device, you cannot trust anything that is computed on the phone. If you want something done securely, do it on your server.

As for your question, this is just how public cryptography (at least RSA) works: you cannot encrypt any data that is longer than the key. The reason there are not libraries for this is that it is impossible. If you need secure email use S/MIME or GPG and don't try to reinvent the wheel. Also note that since the key needs to be in the app, anyone can extract it and decrypt your data. If you just want to send data securely, a better approach might be so send the data over HTTPS. Then you don't need to manage client keys and your data will be protected in transit.

Comment: I agree, the phone is unsecure. But if the data are collected in this device I need at least to protect them, when they are transmitted through the network. Due to other limitations in the project. This data can't be transmitted via to the dedicated server, and have to be e-mailed in protected form. 
In the solution I'm looking for, only the recipient's public key is stored in the phone - which is not secret at all and does not impair security.
I wish I could use GPG, but it doesn't seem to be available in Py4A.

Comment: In any case you cannot encrypt with the public key alone. You need to use symmetric encryption to encrypt the data and then send the encrypted key along. Getting this right is not trivial, so an established solution like S/MIME is preferable. You can always use Java directly or extend Py4a (assuming it is possible).

Comment: That's what I stated in the initial question "Well, I know that in fact I should generate a random temporary symmetric key, encrypt my information with that key, and finally encrypt only this key with the recipient's public key."

Thank you very much. I'll keep searching for the right solution.

Comment: Ah, I now see what you meant. You are not going to find a single function that does exactly that except maybe in an S/MIME library. If you can't use other libraries, you will have to build it from the primitives you have (Cipher, PublicKey, etc).